# R: graphing without ggplot

Tags: r, graph

I am trying to plot 2 graphs (with example data below), from a data set called DATASET (names and examples simplified):

- One with all type A lines, with different colors for local and federal
- One with all type B lines, with different colors for local and federal

[image]

Basically, just a time series plot that illustrates the evolution of each type, and distinguishes local and federal. So I am looking for a graph that puts together all "A" types, but distinguishes local and federal by color; and another graph that illustrates all "B" types, distinguishing by local and federal by color.

I am trying, for the Local type A graph:

```
plot(DATASET$Date [DATASET$Type == "A" & DATASET$Area=="Local"], 
     DATASET$Amount [DATASET$Type == "A" & DATASET$Area=="Local"], 
     type = 'l')
```

But the resulting graph has to be wrong, it appears to mix types A and B, or Local and Federal, I can't tell. The actual data set is quite large.

Could somebody please help me figure out the correct structure of commands?

Comment: Please share `head(data)` or `dput(data)` rather than posting a picture of the data. It makes reproducing the problem much simpler.

Comment: Is there any reason you don't want to use ggplot?

Comment: @Lorenzen, if the answer doesn't work for you please comment else please accept!

Answer (score 0):

Well I would highly recommend using ggplot it would be so much more easier. I tried with some data and I could create a plot given your requirements as follows

```
data <- cars
data[['model']]<-rep(c('Federal','Local'),each=25)
```

This would be equal to your data set for **type**="A"/"B"

```
plot(data$speed[data$model=='Federal'], data$dist[data$model=='Federal'],type='l',col='red',
  main="Dual ordinate plot",xlab="speed",ylab="dist")
legend(4,80,#places the legend at the right place,
    c('Federal','Local')##gives the proper labels
    ,lty=c(1,1)##give the legend proper symbols,
    ,col=c('red','blue'))
par(new=T)##This allows use to superimpose the new plot on the earliar frame
##The yy plot
plot(data$speed[data$model=='Local'], 
data$dist[data$model=='Local'],type='l',col='blue',xlab="",ylab="",axes=F)
axis(side=4)##axis for yy
```

[image]